# Top 10 by Customer - Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm having some issues....how do I get the following code fixed to return the table below as a sum of customers?  I want a total of customer quantities by customer, and then a top 10 list.  So all of the Yellow Rose should be added together and then counted as one entry, instead of all of their shipments showing up individually.

```
select top 10 T1.Quantity, T1.CustName
from
(
select 
     SUM(Tkscale.Qty)Quantity,
        Slcust.Name CustName

from Tkscale with (nolock)
      left outer join Slcust with (nolock) on Tkscale.CustomerID = Slcust.CustomerID 

group by Tkscale.CustomerID, Tkscale.Qty, Slcust.Name
) T1
order by T1.CustName desc, T1.Quantity desc
```

[image]

Comment: 2008 R2 @CodeDifferent

Comment: Don't group by tkscale.qty on the inner query.  It's being summed so it shouldn't be in the group by.

Comment: You might take a look at this article before you continue littering your database with nolock hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 3):

try to remove in grouping 'Tkscale.Qty'

Comment: Thanks!!  Now onto my next step...I'll probably be back.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Tkscale.Qty` from the `GROUP BY` clause in your inner query. I also think that you want top 10 largest customers by quantity, not by their names:

```
select top 10 T1.Quantity, T1.CustName
from
(
select 
     SUM(Tkscale.Qty)Quantity,
        Slcust.Name CustName

from Tkscale with (nolock)
      left outer join Slcust with (nolock) on Tkscale.CustomerID = Slcust.CustomerID 

group by Slcust.Name
) T1
order by T1.Quantity desc, T1.CustName desc
         ^ change the sequence of the ORDER BY clause
```

Comment: You should Group by indexed ID, not a string value (witch shouldn't be indexed...): `group by Tkscale.CustomerID`